# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()

def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.find('tbody')

    teams = []

    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        cols = row.find_all('td')

        teams.append({
            'Место': cols[0].td.text,
            'Команда': [name.text for name in row.find_all('a', {'class': 'name'})],
            'Матчи': cols[2].td.text
            })

    for team in teams:
        print(team)


def main():
    parse(get_html('https://www.sports.ru/epl/table/'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Никак не могу понять что он от меня хочет.19 строка.

Comment: Укажите, на какую строку указывает ошибка

Comment: А лучше, приведите полный текст ошибки. Вероятнее всего, один из `find/findall` ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как `personality13` правильно заметил, автор не заметил что в `cols[0].td` не нужно `.td` вызывать, т.к. в `cols[0]` уже находится тег `td`.

Я приведу полный работающий пример с небольшими своими правками:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parse(html):
    teams = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    for row in soup.select('tbody > tr'):
        cols = row.select('td')

        teams.append({
            'Место': cols[0].text,
            'Команда': [name.text for name in row.select('a[class=name]')],
            'Матчи': cols[2].text
        })

    return teams


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://www.sports.ru/epl/table/'

    import urllib.request
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as rs:
        html = rs.read()

    teams = parse(html)

    for team in teams:
        print(team)
```

Консоль:

```
{'Место': '1', 'Команда': ['Манчестер Юнайтед'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '2', 'Команда': ['Ливерпуль'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '3', 'Команда': ['Хаддерсфилд'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '4', 'Команда': ['Манчестер Сити'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '5', 'Команда': ['Вест Бромвич'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '6', 'Команда': ['Челси'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '7', 'Команда': ['Уотфорд'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '8', 'Команда': ['Саутгемптон'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '9', 'Команда': ['Тоттенхэм'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '10', 'Команда': ['Бернли'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '11', 'Команда': ['Сток Сити'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '12', 'Команда': ['Эвертон'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '13', 'Команда': ['Суонси'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '14', 'Команда': ['Ньюкасл'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '15', 'Команда': ['Лестер'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '16', 'Команда': ['Арсенал'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '17', 'Команда': ['Брайтон'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '18', 'Команда': ['Борнмут'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '19', 'Команда': ['Кристал Пэлас'], 'Матчи': '3'}
{'Место': '20', 'Команда': ['Вест Хэм'], 'Матчи': '3'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def parse(html):
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('tbody')

teams = []

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    teams.append({
        'Место': cols[0].text,
        'Команда': [name.text for name in row.find_all('a', {'class': 'name'})],
        'Матчи': cols[2].text
        })
```

Запутался, бывает).

Comment: У вас не возникало ворнинга при вызове `BeautifulSoup(html)` без второго параметра `UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.`?

Comment: Да, у некоторых бывает. Вместо этого soup = BeautifulSoup(html)  впишите это soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml'). Это необязательно, но для эстетики можно.

Comment: ага, знаю, я так [постоянно так пишу](https://github.com/search?q=user%3Agil9red+BeautifulSoup+lxml&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93), просто и у вас, и автора не было этого параметра, вот и думаю мб что-то не так у меня :D